# Replace rows in one column with values from another if a condition met

Tags: pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, "Yes"], [4, 5, "No"], [7, 8, "Yes"], [3, 5, "No"]],
...      index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd' ],
...      columns=['column_1', 'column_2', 'condition'])

    column_1    column_2    condition
a       1           2        Yes
b       4           5        No
c       7           8        Yes
d       3           5        No
```

I would like to replace the row values in `column_1` with corresponding values in `column_2` when the condition is `"Yes"`. I have been trying to do this using the following code:

```
df.loc[df['condition'] == "Yes", ['column_1']] = df.ix[df['column_1']]
```

Any hint is much appreciated!

Comment: If it is simple assignment, then just `df.loc[df['condition'] == "Yes", 'column_2'] = df['column_1']` is enough.

Comment: Thank you very much. Please copy that as answer and I confirm it! Just a general question. Why providing ix is not necessary here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ix` is deprecated. But aside from that, you do not need any slicer/selector here. Just select with `loc` on the LHS, and pandas will perform index-aligned assignment. So, this is enough:

```
df.loc[df['condition'] == "Yes", 'column_2'] = df['column_1']
```

In indexed aligned assignment, only the indices that are required from`df['column_1']` are pulled in. From,

```
df.loc[df['condition'] == "Yes", 'column_2'] 

a    1
c    7
Name: column_2, dtype: int64
```

We see only the values for index "a" and "c" are needed from `df['column_1']`, everything else is ignored.

Comment: Thank you for thorough explanation!